# How can i run sphinxtrain script?

Tags: python, perl

I'm using sphinx to build my own model for vocal recognition , i've followed the tutorial step by step and all works fine until that point when i should run the python script of **sphinixtrain** (whose role is to execute a set of perl files throw terminal in normal case) but for me, the program only opens the files one by one with a chosen editor without executing them !(watching other tutorials videos, the code bellow works normal)

The code of trainer :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
import getopt, sys, os
training_basedir = ""
sphinxbinpath = ""
sphinxpath = ""

def find_paths():
 global training_basedir
 global sphinxbinpath
 global sphinxpath
 # Find the location of the files, it can be libexec or lib or lib64
 currentpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

 sphinxbinpath = os.path.realpath(currentpath + "/../libexec/sphinxtrain")

 if os.path.exists(currentpath + "/../lib/sphinxtrain/bw"):
    sphinxbinpath = os.path.realpath(currentpath + "/../lib/sphinxtrain/bw")

 if os.path.exists(currentpath + "/../bin/Release/Win32"):
    sphinxbinpath = os.path.realpath(currentpath + "/../bin/Release/Win32")

 # Find the location for the libraries
 sphinxpath = os.path.realpath(currentpath + "/../lib/sphinxtrain")

 if os.path.exists(currentpath + "/../lib64/sphinxtrain/scripts/00.verify"):
    sphinxpath = os.path.realpath(currentpath + "/../lib64/sphinxtrain")

 if os.path.exists(currentpath + "/../scripts/00.verify"):
    sphinxpath = os.path.realpath(currentpath + "/..")

 if not (os.path.exists(sphinxbinpath + "/bw") or os.path.exists(sphinxbinpath + "/bw.exe")):
    print("Failed to find sphinxtrain binaries. Check your installation")
    exit(1)

 # Perl script want forward slashes
 training_basedir = os.getcwd().replace('\\', '/');
 sphinxpath = sphinxpath.replace('\\','/')
 sphinxbinpath = sphinxbinpath.replace('\\','/')

 print("Sphinxtrain path:", sphinxpath)
 print("Sphinxtrain binaries path:", sphinxbinpath)

 def setup(task):
  if not os.path.exists("etc"):
    os.mkdir("etc")

  print("Setting up the database " + task)

  out_cfg = open("./etc/sphinx_train.cfg", "w")
  for line in open(sphinxpath + "/etc/sphinx_train.cfg", "r"):
    line = line.replace("___DB_NAME___", task)
    line = line.replace("___BASE_DIR___", training_basedir)
    line = line.replace("___SPHINXTRAIN_DIR___", sphinxpath)
    line = line.replace("___SPHINXTRAIN_BIN_DIR___", sphinxbinpath)
    out_cfg.write(line)
  out_cfg.close()

  out_cfg = open("etc/feat.params", "w")
  for line in open(sphinxpath + "/etc/feat.params", "r"):
    out_cfg.write(line)
  out_cfg.close()
 steps = [
  "000.comp_feat/slave_feat.pl",
  "00.verify/verify_all.pl",
  "0000.g2p_train/g2p_train.pl",
  "01.lda_train/slave_lda.pl",
  "02.mllt_train/slave_mllt.pl",
  "05.vector_quantize/slave.VQ.pl",
  "10.falign_ci_hmm/slave_convg.pl",
  "11.force_align/slave_align.pl",
  "12.vtln_align/slave_align.pl",
  "20.ci_hmm/slave_convg.pl",
  "30.cd_hmm_untied/slave_convg.pl",
  "40.buildtrees/slave.treebuilder.pl",
  "45.prunetree/slave.state-tying.pl",
  "50.cd_hmm_tied/slave_convg.pl",
  "60.lattice_generation/slave_genlat.pl",
  "61.lattice_pruning/slave_prune.pl",
  "62.lattice_conversion/slave_conv.pl",
  "65.mmie_train/slave_convg.pl",
  "90.deleted_interpolation/deleted_interpolation.pl",
  "decode/slave.pl",
  ]
  def run_stages(stages):
  for stage in stages.split(","):
    for step in steps:
            name = step.split("/")[0].split(".")[-1]
            if name == stage:
                ret = os.system(sphinxpath + "/scripts/" + step)
                if ret != 0:
                     exit(ret)

 def run_from(stage):
  found = False
  for step in steps:
    name = step.split("/")[0].split(".")[-1]
    if name == stage or found:
        found = True
        ret = os.system(sphinxpath + "/scripts/" + step)
        if ret != 0:
            exit(ret)
 def run():
  print("Running the training")
  for step in steps:
    ret = os.system(sphinxpath + "/scripts/" + step)
    if ret != 0:
       exit(ret)
 def usage():
  print ("")
  print ("Sphinxtrain processes the audio files and creates and acoustic model ")
  print ("for CMUSphinx toolkit. The data needs to have a certain layout ")
  print ("See the tutorial http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam ")
  print ("for details")
  print ("")
  print ("Usage: sphinxtrain [options] <command>")
  print ("")
  print ("Commands:")
  print ("     -t <task> setup - copy configuration into database")
  print ("     [-s <stage1,stage2,stage3>] [-f <stage>] run - run the training or just selected 
  stages")

def main():

 try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "ht:s:f:", ["help", "task", "stages", "from"])
 except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print(str(err))
    usage()
    sys.exit(-1)

 task = None
 stages = None
 from_stage = None

 for o, a in opts:
    if o in ("-t", "--task"):
        task = a
    if o in ("-f", "--from"):
        from_stage = a
    if o in ("-s", "--stages"):
        stages = a
    if o in ("-h", "--help"):
            usage()

 if len(args) == 0:
    usage()
    sys.exit(-1)

 command = args[0]

 find_paths()

 if command == "setup":
    if task == None:
        print("No task name defined")
        sys.exit(-1)        
    setup(task)
 elif command == "run":
    if stages != None:
        run_stages(stages)
    elif from_stage != None:
        run_from(from_stage)
    else:
        run()
 else:
    run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to solve this is to be explicit about calling the Perl interpreter in your os.system call

i.e.

```
ret = os.system('perl ' + sphinxpath + "/scripts/" + step)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by associating perl files ( with pl extension) to perl.exe

Comment: Can you guide me how to associate the perl files to perl.exe?